# Adding .js files to MOSS

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, deployment

When I try to deploy .js files as part of a feature, not in the _layouts directory I get the following error:

Cannot make a cache safe URL for 'myfile.js'

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Where are you trying to deploy your file to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We place our .js files under Style Library for a given site collection.  We got our solution template from a consultant so I'm not comfortable sharing the files/details on the Internet, but provisionfiles.xml (element manifest) has the .js files listed under the CSSFiles module.

EDIT: Googling for this information is difficult.  I found that ([module RootWebOnly](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=module+RootWebOnly&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=&aqi=)) and ([module cssfiles RootWebOnly](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=module+cssfiles+RootWebOnly&aq=f&oq=&aqi=)) return decent results.

Answer (score 0):

Within your feature folder (under 12/template/features); check elements.xml; and make sure the js file is being deployed to \12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

Comment: You should create a custom folder under layouts in which to place your files as well.